# MongoDB storing logs for account as embedded object

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to understand what is the best method of storing large data on MongoDB for faster reads and write with minimum impact to hardware resources.

Currently we have SQL Azure database that stores audit logs for users for the individual accounts. The table currently has total records of about 2 million and its growing daily.

I would thinking of moving to MongoBB with one object per accounts with all the logs objects embedded. The logs data per account could grow overtime and currently largest logs set on an account is about 200,000 logs and we would like that to be unlimited.

accountLogs document

```
{
_accountid: 100,
Logs: [
        {
          username: 'xyz'
          action: 'logged in'
          actionDate: 01/03/2015
          companyid: 123
        },
        {
          username: 'xyz'
          action: 'logged out'
          actionDate: 01/03/2015
          companyid: 123
        }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your case log for the specific account is not having upper bound and mongodb document having hard limit of 16 mb per document, your current solution will not work. Even if the data reaches more than 2-4 MB size it will be difficult to query as the array size will be too high. One of the solution you can apply is to create the bucker per account so the schema will be look like this . Now you can keep the global count for the account id with the number of logs so far and divide it with the bucket size example 10000  , so it will be like this. You can use the upsert command of the mongodb to create a new bucket in case it does not exists .

```
    int bucketId = totallog / bucketsize;
```

Now you have uniform size of bucket for the log and make composite key on account id and bucket id for fast search.

```
    {
      _accountid: 100,
       bucketId : 4,
    Logs: [
    {
      username: 'xyz'
      action: 'logged in'
      actionDate: 01/03/2015
      companyid: 123
    },
    {
      username: 'xyz'
      action: 'logged out'
      actionDate: 01/03/2015
      companyid: 123
    }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: How about create a log collection with one document per log that includes accountid, will this have any performance benefit if i query for a single account

Answer (score 0):

the best method of storing large data on MongoDB for faster reads and write with minimum impact to hardware resources is to plan your queries to be satisfied by indexed fields...   you post a sample doc of 1 acct w/ logged on/logged off fields - essentially the acct's session.  this is fine, assuming you will query on those fields and that those fields will be indexed.  the data is minimal such that the index itself may satisfy the query - this is called a covered query and is the most efficient approach.